# jQuery Copy and append tr's as many as selecting

Tags: jquery

*HTML:*

```
<table id="mytable">
<tr>
    <td>
        <select name="antal_tidspunkter" id="antal_tidspunkter">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<!-- These three <tr>s below should be duplicated to under each other -->
<tr>
    <td>This should be duplicated</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>This too</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Hey, me too!</td>
</tr>
<!-- Above should be duplicated as of many you select in the select -->
</table>
```

*JavaScript:*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#antal_tidspunkter').change(function(){
        //
    });
});​
```

*Here's the sample:* http://jsfiddle.net/PMXmY

I would like to do so when you change the selector to 2 it should appear a duplicate of the current 3 tr's, so total 6 tr's..

I have wrote the jquery change() handler for the selector, but how can I do so it duplicates the three tr's and append them under.

So when you have chosen 3, it should appear total 9 `<tr>`'s, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/PMXmY/2/ (this is not working I have just manually duplicated the tr's in the html)

Comment: Post your code inside the question.

Comment: So, if you choose 2, you should all of a sudden have 4 trs, then if you choose 3, you should have 13, and then 6, there will be 49? please clarify. is it addative? or does it replace whats there, only add in addition to whats there, etc.

Comment: Is this list of trs to be duplicated known ahead of time? If you selected "2" after "3", would there be 18, or 6 rows?

Comment: Will it always be only the *last three rows* that get cloned/appended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this solution?

```
$("#antal_tidspunkter").on("change", function() {
    $("#mytable tr:gt(3)").remove();
    for (var i = 1; i < this.value; i++) {
        $("#mytable tr:not(:first):lt(3)").clone().appendTo("#mytable");
    }
});​
```

If you don't need to remove the cloned rows every change time, just delete the second line.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/PMXmY/16/

Comment: Hey this works fine in jsfiddle but on my site it says has no on() method

Comment: @Karem You should update your jQuery to the newer version. Otherwise, use `bind` instead of `on`.

Comment: Thanks now it works! Although on my real page i have a tr before the selector, like this http://jsfiddle.net/PMXmY/17/ and when i now choose it clones the wrong tr's, not like before

Comment: I tried to edit in what you have done, and then i saw that it skips the :first, but i also need it to skip the second and then take the 3 tr's

Comment: @Karem Then you should have mentioned this in the question. Here is it: http://jsfiddle.net/PMXmY/18/.

Comment: thanks ! this works fine now but i noticed when you select 3 it appears 4 and when you select 4 it appears 8 or something ?? It works only right if you select 1 or 2 in the #antal_tidspunkter selector.. :/

Comment: @Karem Ha! That was my stupidness :) I forgot to add an extra selector. Check now: http://jsfiddle.net/PMXmY/19/. It should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#antal_tidspunkter').change(function(){
        // get the number selected and subtract one to 
        // get the number of clones you need to append
        var num = parseInt($(this).val()) - 1;
        
        // the target to which the items will be appended
        var target = $('#mytable');

        //loop that will run as many times as the number that was selected
        for(i =0; i < num; i++) {
            //loop to clone and append only the first three tr's
            for(j = 1; j <=3; j++) {                
                // find the tr, clone it and append it to the target
                target.find('tr').eq(j).clone().appendTo(target);

            }
        }
    });
});​
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/PMXmY/15/)

*Commented the code so you can understand it.*

Comment: You cant go back to 1 here eg